# Not Letting Me Turn On Registration

Tags: users

When I try to change my ACCOUNT settings at admin/config/people/accounts

The new state (visitors) doesn't stay checked at Who can register accounts. It reverts just back to admin.

Does anyone know why?

**Note**:  I had a look in settings and all the files around it (D8). But I cannot see anything similar.

Answer (score 0):

The config variable might be hard-coded in your codebase.

You could look for the string:

`$conf[` or `$conf['user_register'] = 0`

For example, in *settings.php* or elsewhere.

The exact string may vary depending on your codebase, e.g quotes, spaces etc..

That would override the variable configuration setting in the UI.

Comment: Thanks David. I had a look in settings and all the files around it (D8) but i cant see anything similar. I think you must be along the right lines though. I will keep at it thanks

Comment: @RegGordon Yes, the above is for D7, please remember to tag your question with the Drupal version in the future to make it easier to determine which version the question is for, thx.